# Using PnP JS: How Get users who have permissions on a particular list item

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, pnp-js-core

I am trying to get the user and their permissions for the particular item from SharePoint document library using PnP JS.

PnP query:

```
sp.web.lists.getByTitle("Documents").items.getById(211).roleAssignments()
```

By using above query I am getting the user ID and but the user name and the permission.

Please let me know what mistake I am doing I tried a lot but not able to fetch

I need to complete this task using PnP JS.

Comment: show the data you're getting back. Is it just an array of IDs? If so you'll probably have to cross-reference the user info list